# Does using Activity Monitor have an effect on server performance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, activity-monitor

Our SQL Server VLDB is being monitored by Activity Monitor on a networked machine.
95% of all traced statements can be attributed to this tool, but is it known to have a negative effect on server/network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES. Beware of the "observer effect."

[This article](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events) is about you using trace and extended events directly, but Activity Monitor uses similar technology under the covers - it doesn't have any magical, no-cost ways of collecting performance information.

There are several monitoring tools out there that do a better job at this than Activity Monitor, some more so than others. There are also free scripts like [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) and [sp_BlitzFirst](https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/) that are more honest with you about what's really going on on your servers (see [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/why-i-dont-use-sql-server-activity-monitor/)). I strongly suggest you try some of those out and don't open Activity Monitor or Profiler at all.

Comment: Just to extend this, Kendra Little also wrote a little [blog post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/why-i-dont-use-sql-server-activity-monitor/) on the potential "pit falls" of using Activity Monitor, in terms of visual data, but not with regard to server performance

Comment: @DimUser yep, I linked to that post in my answer...